# how can I receive Newline delimited JSON in my client?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I can't find any way to deal with that topic. Basically I'm receiving from my API a stream in ndJson format. Just found a npm module to manage ndjson in server side. How can I set up a client play with Newline delimited JSON. Any suggestion will be helpfull. Thanks

Comment: How about `JSON.stringify (data,2)`

Answer (score 1):

You divide you input up on new lines. How you do this depends on how you are getting the input.

You might have it all arrive as one big string, in which case you can `str.split("\n")` it.

You might be getting it coming on continuously, in which case you'll probably be grabbing a number of bytes each time and will want to split each chunk as above, but prepend the last portion of it to the new chunk (to handle a line being split over two chunks of data).

Once you have your input divided up, run each JSON text (which will be each member of the array if you use split) through `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. it works. to take the data I had to use `.always` then inside the callback I had `.responseText` with my data. I replaced the /n with "," and used JSON.parse(text). Use .responseText is a bit strange.. is there any other way to take the data?

Comment: There is nothing strange about getting the JSON formatted text in the response out out of the responseText property. That is what it is for.